# Rightmark Header Not Showing on the second page of section 1 of my document

Tags: header-footer

I am having challenges with the `\rightmark` command in the header. It is working well on other parts of my document except on page 2 where the subsection name is not appearing in the header when it is supposed to be appearing. My question is how to fix this error, the header of the document is empty on page 2 when it is not supposed to be empty. Below is my MWE:

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass[12pt,openany,twoside]{article}
\raggedbottom
\let\cleardoublepage=\clearpage
\usepackage[
a4paper
]{geometry}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{conjecture}{Conjecture}[section]
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[section]
\newtheorem*{keyword*}{Keywords}

\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\HRule{\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1.5pt}}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hhline}
\fancypagestyle{fancy}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[OL]{\leftmark}
    \fancyhead[ER]{\rightmark}
    \fancyfoot{}
    \fancyfoot[RE,RO]{\thepage}
    \fancyfoot[LO,LE]{ GROUP ASSIGNMENT}
    \renewcommand\headrule
    {{     \nointerlineskip 
            \color{black}\rule{1\headwidth}{2.5pt}%   
    }}
}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{}%
    \fancyhead[OL]{\leftmark}
    \fancyhead[ER]{\rightmark}
    \renewcommand\headrule
    {{     \color{uzblue}\rule{1\headwidth}{0pt}%         
    }}   
    \fancyfoot{}
    \fancyfoot[RE,RO]{\thepage}
    \fancyfoot[LO,LE]{GROUP ASSIGNMENT}
}

\pagestyle{fancy}   
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\footruleskip}{3pt} 


\usepackage[marginal]{footmisc}
\renewcommand\footnoterule{\vspace*{-3pt}%
    \hrule width 2in height 1.4pt \vspace*{2.6pt}}
\setlength\footnotemargin{10pt}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[noindentafter,calcwidth]{titlesec}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{calc,pifont} 

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[ragged]{sidecap}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{regexpatch}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{apptools}
 
\usepackage{fontspec}% added
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}


\newcommand{\zerodisplayskips}{%
    \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}}
\appto{\normalsize}{\zerodisplayskips}
\appto{\small}{\zerodisplayskips}
\appto{\footnotesize}{\zerodisplayskips}

\begin{document} 


    \setcounter{page}{1}
    % Ends the declared geometry for the titlepage
    \restoregeometry
    %--------------------------
    
    \begin{keyword*}
        Security Market Line (SML), Capital Market Line (CML), Capital Asset Pricing Model (CAPM), Expected return, Volatility, Beta
    \end{keyword*}  
    
    \section{Introduction}
    
    Capital market theory expanded the concepts
    introduced by Markowitz portfolio theory by
    introducing the notion that investors could borrow
    or lend at the risk-free rate in addition to forming
    efficient portfolios of risky assets. This insight led
    to the development of the capital market line
    (CML), which can be viewed as a new efficient
    frontier that emanates from the risk-free rate
    and is tangent to the Markowitz efficient frontier.
    The point of tangency is called the market
    portfolio.
    The CML’s main contribution is the relationship it
    specifies between the risk and expected return of a
    well-diversified portfolio. The CML makes it clear
    that the market portfolio is the single collection of
    risky assets that maximizes the ratio of expected
    risk premium to portfolio volatility. The investment prescription of the CML is that investors
    cannot do better, on average, than when they
    divide their investment funds between the riskless asset and the market portfolio. The capital asset pricing model (CAPM) generalizes
    the risk-return trade-off in the capital market line
    (CML) to allow for a consideration of individual
    securities as well as entire portfolios. To make this
    extension, the CAPM redefines the relevant measure of risk as beta, which is the systematic component of a security's volatility relative to that of
    the market portfolio. 
    
    \subsection{Definition of Key Terms}
    \begin{definition}[Expected Return]
        A computation for the return of a security 
        based on the average payoff expected.
    \end{definition}
    
    \begin{definition}[Volatility]
        The standard deviation of a return.
    \end{definition}
    
    \begin{definition}[Capital Market Line (CML)]
        When plotting expected returns 
        versus volatility, the line from the risk-free investment through 
        the efficient portfolio of risky stocks (the portfolio that has the 
        highest possible Sharpe ratio). In the context of the CAPM, it 
        is the line from the risk-free investment through the market 
        portfolio. It shows the highest possible expected return that 
        can be obtained for any given volatility
    \end{definition}
    
    \begin{definition}[Capital Asset Pricing Model (CAPM)]
        An equilibrium model 
        of the relationship between risk and return that characterizes 
        a security’s expected return based on its beta with the market 
        portfolio.
    \end{definition} 
    
    \begin{definition}[Beta]
        The expected percent change in the excess return of a 
        security for a 1\% change in the excess return of the market (or 
        other benchmark) portfolio
    \end{definition}
    
    \begin{definition}[Security Market Line (SML)]
        The pricing implication of the 
        CAPM, it specifies a linear relation between the risk premium 
        of a security and its beta with the market portfolio.
    \end{definition}
    
    \section{Comparison and Contrast of Graphical Features of the CML and SML}
    \subsection{Capital Market Theory}
    Capital market theory extends Markowitz model to a situation when a 
    risk free asset is introduced in the capital market. It also assumes that 
    investors are rational and mean variance optimizers as assumed by 
    Markowitz Portfolio Theory. The capital market line is given in the following equation:
    \begin{align*}
        E[R_{p}]&=R_{f}+\frac{\sigma_{p}}{\sigma_{m}}\left(  E[R_{m}]-R_{f}\right)  
        \intertext{where}
        E[R_{p}]&=\text{the expected return of a portfolio;}\\
        R_{f}&=\text{the risk free interest rate};\\
        E[R_{m}]&=\text{the expected return on market portfolio}\\
        \sigma_{p}&=\text{standard deviation of the portfolio, and}\\
        \sigma_{m}&=\text{standard deviation of the market portfolio}
    \end{align*}
    The capital market line shows that the return from a portfolio depends 
    upon the risk free rate, reward per unit of market risk and total risk of the 
    portfolio. The higher the risk the higher will be the expected return.
    
    The CML has the following features:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item CML shows a linear and a positive relationship between expected 
        return and risk of a portfolio.
        \item It originates from $ R_{f} $ , hence the intercept of CML is $ R_{f} $.
        \item The slope of CML is the reward to variability ratio i.e $$\frac{1}{\sigma_{m}}\left(  E[R_{m}]-R_{f}\right)$$
        \item CML is tangent to original efficient frontier at the Mean Variance Efficient Porfolio.
        \item Only efficient portfolios consisting of risk free asset and the Mean Variance Efficient Porfolio lies on CML.
        \item CML is upward sloping because price of a risk must be positive
        since investors are risk averse.
        
    \end{itemize}
    
    
    
    \subsection{Capital Asset Pricing Model}
    The capital asset pricing model (CAPM) is a model used to determine a 
    theoretically appropriate required rate of return of an asset, to make 
    decisions about adding assets to a well-diversified portfolio. It shows that 
    there is a linear and a positive relationship between expected return and 
    systematic risk. As per this model only systematic risk is priced, 
    unsystematic risk being diversifiable risk is not priced in the capital 
    market. Hence the Capital Market Line which shows the relationship 
    between and total risk should show a relationship between expected
    return and systematic risk indicated by $ \beta $ factor. The linear relationship between the return required on an investment 
    (whether in stock market securities or in business operations) and its 
    systematic risk is represented by the CAPM formula:
    \begin{align*}
        E[R_{i}]&=R_{i}=R_{f}+\underbrace{\beta_{i}\times\left( E[R_{m}]-R_{f}\right)}_{\text{Risk premium for security } i}
        \intertext{where $ \beta_{i}$ is the beta of the security with respect to the market portfolio}
        \beta_{i}&=\frac{\overbrace{SD(R_{i})\times Corr(R_{i},R_{m})}^{\text{Volatility of $ i $ that is common with the market}}}{SD(R_{m})}=\frac{Cov(R_{i},R_{m})}{Var[R_{m}]}
    \end{align*}
    The $ \beta $\footnote{is a measure of the systematic risk in other words} of a security measures its volatility due to market risk relative to the market as a whole, and thus captures the security’s sensitivity to market risk.
    \subsubsection{Security Market Line}\label{subsub2.2.1}
    Security market line (SML) is the representation of the capital asset 
    pricing model. It displays the expected rate of return of an individual 
    security as a function of systematic, non-diversifiable risk. The risk of an 
    individual risky security reflects the volatility of the return from security 
    rather than the return of the market portfolio. The risk in these individual 
    risky securities reflects the systematic risk.
    The SML essentially graphs the results from the capital asset pricing 
    model (CAPM) formula. The $ x$\textendash axis represents the risk (beta), and the $ y$\textendash axis represents the expected return. The market risk premium is 
    determined from the slope of the SML.
    The relationship between $ \beta $ and required return is plotted on the securities 
    market line (SML), which shows expected return as a function of $ \beta $. The 
    intercept is the nominal risk-free rate available for the market, while the 
    slope is the market premium, $ E[R_{m}]− R_{f} $. The securities market line can 
    be regarded as representing a single-factor model of the asset price, 
    where Beta is exposure to changes in value of the Market. The equation 
    of the SML is thus:
    \begin{align*}
        SML=E[R_{i}]&=R_{f}+\beta_{i}(E[R_{m}]-R_{f})
        \intertext{where}
        E[R_{i}]&=\text{expected return on security}\\
        E[R_{m}]&=\text{expected return on market portfolio}\\
        \beta_{i}&=\text{non-diversifiable or systematic risk}\\
        R_{m}&=\text{market rate of return}\\
        R_{f}&=\text{risk free rate}
    \end{align*}
    It is a useful tool in determining if an asset being considered for a 
    portfolio offers a reasonable expected return for risk. Individual securities 
    are plotted on the SML graph. If the security's expected return versus risk 
    is plotted above the SML, it is undervalued since the investor can expect 
    a greater return for the inherent risk. And a security plotted below the 
    SML is overvalued since the investor would be accepting less return for 
    the amount of risk assumed.
    %width=0.7\linewidth, height=.7\textheight
    
    When used in portfolio management, the SML represents the 
    investment's opportunity cost (investing in a combination of the market 
    portfolio and the risk-free asset). All the correctly priced securities are 
    plotted on the SML. The assets above the line are undervalued because 
    for a given amount of risk (beta), they yield a higher return. The assets 
    below the line are overvalued because for a given amount of risk, they 
    yield a lower return.
    
    \section{Similarities Between CML and SML }
    
    \subsection{Graphical Similiarities}
    The similarities between the CML and SML as models of the risk-return tradeoff are that both are a graphical representation of risk-return combinations. Both the CML and SML intersect the vertical axis or the $ y $\textendash axis at the risk-free rate point.
    
    \subsection{Risk-Return Tradeoff Modeling}
    Both the CML and SML is used to model the risk-return tradeoff for portfolios though the SML is used for both individual securities and portfolios of securities.
    
    \subsection{Market Portfolio}
    The market portfolio is assumed to be the same portfolio in both models. Both models combine a risk-free asset and offer opportunities to leverage the risky asset portfolio by borrowing at the risk-free rate.
    
    \section{Differences Between CML and SML}
    \subsection{Risk Coefficients}
    While standard deviation, $ \sigma $ is the measure of risk in CML, $ \beta $ 
    coefficient determines the risk factors of the SML. In SML, the risk is defined as total risk and is measured by $ \sigma $. In SML, risk is defined as the systematic risk and is measured by $ \beta $.
    
    \subsection{What Each Line Defines}
    While the Capital Market Line graphs define efficient portfolios, the 
    Security Market Line graphs define both efficient and non-efficient 
    portfolios. Thus, the CML is valid for efficient portfolios only while the SML is valid for all portfolios and all individual securities. As a result of this all efficient portfolios lie along the CML while SML applies to individual securities, efficient portfolios and inefficient portfolios.
    
    \subsection{Superiority When Measuring Risk Factors}
    The Capital Market Line is considered to be superior than the Security Market Line when measuring 
    the risk factors. The CML is considered to be superior to the efficient frontier\footnote{A set of optimal portfolios that offers the highest expected return for a defined level of risk or the lowest risk for a 
        given level of expected return.
    }
    since it takes into account the 
    inclusion of a risk-free asset in the portfolio. The Capital Asset Pricing Model (CAPM) demonstrates 
    that the market portfolio is essentially the efficient frontier. This is achieved visually through the 
    Security Market Line (SML). All 
    points along the CML have superior risk-return profiles to any portfolio on the efficient frontier, 
    with the exception of the Market Portfolio, the point on the efficient frontier to which the CML is the 
    tangent. From a CML perspective, this portfolio is composed entirely of the risky asset, the market, 
    and has no holding of the risk free asset ,i.e., money is neither invested in, nor borrowed from the 
    money market account.
    
    \subsection{What Each Line Determines}
    Where the market portfolio and risk free assets are determined by the 
    CML, all security factors are determined by the SML. The CML is derived by drawing a tangent line from the intercept point on the efficient frontier to the 
    point where the expected return equals the risk-free rate of return. The tangency point M represents the market portfolio, so named since all rational 
    investors (minimum variance criterion) should hold their risky assets in the same proportions as their 
    weights in the market portfolio. 
    
    \subsection{What Each Line Depicts}
    The CML is a line that is used to show the rates of return, which 
    depends on risk-free rates of return and levels of risk for a specific 
    portfolio. SML\footnote{which is also called a Characteristic Line} is a graphical 
    representation of the market’s risk and return at a given time. The CML is performed by mixing the market portfolio with the risk free asset while the SML depicts the trade-off between systematic risk and the expected return for all assets. The CML specifies the equilibrium relationship between expected return and total risk for efficient diversified portfolios while the SML specifies the equilibrium relationship between expected return and systematic risk.
    
    \subsection{Model to Which Each Line forms a Basis}
    The CML is based on the Capital Market Theory while the SML is based on the CAPM. Capital Market Line (CML) is a line based on the Capital Market Theory used in the Capital Asset Pricing Model to illustrate the rates 
    of return for efficient portfolios depending on the risk-free rate of return and the level of risk 
    (standard deviation) for a particular portfolio while the Security market line (SML) is the representation of the Capital Asset Pricing Model. It displays the 
    expected rate of return of an individual security as a function of systematic,
    non-diversifiable risk (its beta).
    The SML essentially graphs the results from the capital asset pricing model (CAPM) formula. 
    
    
    \subsection{Equation of Each Line}\label{sub4.7}
    The CML equation is given by
    \begin{align*}
        E[R_{p}]&=R_{f}+\frac{\sigma_{p}}{\sigma_{m}}\left(  E[R_{m}]-R_{f}\right)  
        \intertext{where}
        E[R_{p}]&=\text{the expected return of a portfolio;}\\
        R_{f}&=\text{the risk free interest rate};\\
        E[R_{m}]&=\text{the expected return on market portfolio}\\
        \sigma_{p}&=\text{standard deviation of the portfolio, and}\\
        \sigma_{m}&=\text{standard deviation of the market portfolio}
        \intertext{while the SML equation is }
        SML=E[R_{i}]&=R_{f}+\beta_{i}(E[R_{m}]-R_{f})
        \intertext{where}
        E[R_{i}]&=\text{expected return on security}\\
        E[R_{m}]&=\text{expected return on market portfolio}\\
        \beta_{i}&=\text{non-diversifiable or systematic risk}\\
        R_{m}&=\text{market rate of return}\\
        R_{f}&=\text{risk free rate}
    \end{align*}
    Now the intercept of each line is the risk free rate denoted $ R_{f} $. On the other hand, the slope of the CML is given by $$\frac{1}{\sigma_{m}}\left(  E[R_{m}]-R_{f}\right)$$ while the slope of the SML is given by $$E[R_{m}]-R_{f}$$ 
    
    \subsection{CML and SML slopes in Portfolio Evaluation}
    From Subsection \ref{sub4.7} we indicated the slopes of the CML and SML and in this subsection, we present the use of slope in portfolio evaluation.  The slope of the CML is gives us the Sharpe ratio of the market portfolio while the slope of the SML is the Treynor ratio of the market portfolio since $ \beta=1 $. Following from the Efficient Market Hypothesis (EMH)\footnote{Efficient market hypothesis (EMH) asserts that financial markets are “informationally efficient”, which means one 
        cannot consistently achieve returns in excess of average market returns on a risk-adjusted basis, given the information 
        available at the time the investment is made.}, all assets should have both the Sharpe ratio and Treynor ratio less than or equal to that of the market. All of the portfolios on the CML have the same Sharpe ratio as that of the market portfolio, and all of the portfolios on the SML have the same Treynor ratio as does the market portfolio.
    \section{Conclusions}
    Like the CML, the SML still confirms that the optimum portfolio is the market portfolio. Because the return on a portfolio (or security) depends on whether it follows market prices as a whole, the closer the correlation between a portfolio (security) and the market index, then the greater will be its expected return. Finally, the SML predicts that both portfolios and securities with higher beta values will have higher returns and vice versa. Unfortunately, the CML only calibrates total risk $ \sigma_{p} $ not all of which is diversifiable. Fortunately, the SML offers investors a lifeline, by discriminating between non-systemic and systemic risk. The latter is defined by a beta factor that measures relative (systematic) risk, which explains how rational investors with different utility (risk-return) requirements can choose an optimum portfolio by borrowing or lending at the risk-free rate. Like the CML, the security
    market line (SML) shows that the relationship
    between risk and expected return is a straight
    line with a positive slope. The SML provides investors with a tool for judging whether securities are
    undervalued or overvalued given their level of systematic (beta) risk.
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: I may be mistaking something, but `\rightmark` is defined to appear only on right-hand (odd-numbered) pages.  Page 2 is even-numbered, a left-hand page.

Comment: Pages 4, 6,... have the right header appearing. Im not sure what could be causing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be solved using the package `extramarks`  and `\fancyhead[RE]{\lastrightmark}`

It is already included in the `fancyhdr` distribution so there is no need to download or install anything.

[image: a]

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{extramarks} % added<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\fancypagestyle{fancy}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[OL]{\leftmark}
    \fancyhead[RE]{\lastrightmark} % changed<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \fancyfoot{}
    \fancyfoot[RE,RO]{\thepage}
    \fancyfoot[LO,LE]{ GROUP ASSIGNMENT}
    \renewcommand\headrule
    {{     \nointerlineskip 
            \color{black}\rule{1\headwidth}{2.5pt}%   
    }}
}
```

`extramarks` and its multiple uses is described the section #25 of the `fancyhdr` doc.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following does what you want

```
\fancyhead[ER]{%
  \IfMarksEqualTF{2e-right-nonempty}{top}{first}
    {\rightmark}
    {\FirstMark{2e-right-nonempty}}%
  }
```

This needs an uptodate TeX distribution. For more information see [ltmarks-doc.pdf](https://ctan.space-pro.be/tex-archive/macros/latex/base/ltmarks-doc.pdf)